# Creating ViewModels WIth Common Properties with OnPropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, mvvm

I relised I have lots of models view models with those two properties

```
public Visibility OkButtonVisibility
{
get{  return _OkButtonVisibility;}
set{ 
_OkButtonVisibility = value;
RaisePropertyChanged("OkButtonVisibility");
}

}

public Visibility CancelButtonVisibility
{
get{  return _CancelButtonVisibility;}
set{ 
_CancelButtonVisibility = value;
RaisePropertyChanged("CancelButtonVisibility");
}

}
```

I wanted to create attachable interface for them like this:

```
Interface IOKandCancelButtonsVM
{
 public Visibility OkButtonVisibility
{
get{  return _OkButtonVisibility;}
set{ 
_OkButtonVisibility = value;
RaisePropertyChanged("OkButtonVisibility");
}

}

public Visibility CancelButtonVisibility
{
get{  return _CancelButtonVisibility;}
set{ 
_CancelButtonVisibility = value;
RaisePropertyChanged("CancelButtonVisibility");
}

}
```

and have my viewmodels that use this to inherite them and another interfaces with proxy properties like this

```
class VM1:BaseVM,IOKandCancelButtonsVM,IOtherCommonPropertyVM
{ 

}
```

but then I relaised my new interfaces don't impliment `INotifyChanged`.
would it be a bad idea to have`IOKandCancelButtonsVM` impliment `INotifyChanged`
and have `VM1` explicitly impliment `BaseVM`?

I never dealt with class inheriting same interface twice and not sure what to do.

**this is only an example less than half of the VMs use those I have a few hundred properties, many shared over dozens of screens. i need a more elegant solution than sticking all on thos into the BaseViewModel**

Comment: erm why -1 with no comment? is the question badly formed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have an implementation in your interface definition. This means that your `IOKandCancelButtonsVM` definition is incorrect.

> would it be a bad idea to have IOKandCancelButtonsVM impliment BaseVM

Yes it would be a very bad idea - impossible in fact - interfaces cannot implement or extend classes.

Since you asked for opinion on how to structure your code, I will also throw this out there: remove any reference to 'visibility' from your viewmodel. **Do not** return a System.Visibility value from your viewmodel.

A viewmodel shouldn't know anything about the view. The semantically correct way to do this is to simply return a flag from the viewmodel, and use a converter to change it to a Visibility value in the binding - there is even a ready made converter in the framework for doing this: [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx). Try to avoid any mention of UI related terms in your VM even if it is returning a bool - it is a good practice which leads to tighter and more disciplined code, using those names willy nilly will eventually lead to smelly code.

I have a blog post which illustrates a nice approach to property change notifications: [Streamlining property notifications in MVVM](http://techfilth.blogspot.co.nz/2010/02/streamlining-property-notifications-in.html).

Just to make it clear, I am advising that you get rid of any ideas you have about `IOKandCancelButtonsVM` interfaces, by all means include simple boolean properties on a base viewmodel that will be extended by many other viewmodels that will be bound to dialogs with OK/Cancel buttons.

To diagram this in text it would look like this:

> *YourBaseVm* <-- *BaseVmUsedByDialogs* <-- SpecificDialogVm

(note the italicising which indicates the class is abstract)

Comment: that doesn't answer my question. and of couse I meant impliment INotifyChanged

Comment: @NahumLitvin - I've added a helpful link. My answer addresses a lot of your question and points out problems with your current approach - what don't you understand?

Comment: theres a little problem with your approach called. HUGE HUGE project fulll of horrible design. its too late to fix. all I can do is to try to improve the situation abit. my approach can be gained with several extract to interface clicks. your requires weeks of rewriting.

Comment: @NahumLitvin I sympathise about the huge horrible design, however you can still use this approach with the new stuff and then easily convert the existing VMs to this approach as well. The refactoring usually involves changing the inheritance of the VM class to use the new base VMs, and removing redundant code that is implemented by the base VMs. I've had to do this exact thing in the past, it can be tedious but isn't particularly hard to do.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you already have a base viewmodel class. Just add the two properties there. You might want to create a second base inheriting from the first, which you use when those two properties are required, so in case their not, there is no overhead.

Comment: less than half of the VMs use those I have a few hundred properties, many shared over dozens of screens. i need a more general solution

Answer (score 1):

Why not to go for `virtual properties` in your base class BaseVM with default functionality implemented in it. In case other derived classes want to extend it they can always override it as per funcitonality required.

Make sure your BaseVM is implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just create an abstract base class, and have the ViewModels that need those properties inherit from it. Keep it simple.

```
abstract class BaseDialogVM : BaseVM
{
    private Visibility _OkButtonVisibility;
    public Visibility OkButtonVisibility {
        get { return _OkButtonVisibility; }
        set { 
           _OkButtonVisibility = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged("OkButtonVisibility");
        }
    }

    private Visibility _CancelButtonVisibility;
    public Visibility CancelButtonVisibility {
        get { return _CancelButtonVisibility; }
        set { 
           _CancelButtonVisibility = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged("CancelButtonVisibility");
        }
    }
}

class VM1 : BaseDialogVM { /*...*/ }
```